# C# Verify digital signature in PDF (with private key)

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I'm signing on a pdf file using a .pfx that stored in my DB,

I want to enable users to upload the signed PDF file and get approval that the certificate is **my** certificate.

As I understand the signed PDF contains:

1)signed file

2)hashed (signed file + private key)

3)public key

So I and everyone else can validate that the pdf is signed correctly and not manipulated like this:

```
    public key + hashed value = result. 

then compare the result to the signed file.
```

I want to validate that the certificate is made with mine pk.
So I need to do something like that:

```
    private + signed file = result.

then I can compare the result to the hashed.
```

There is a way of doing it with itextsharp?

Thanks!

Comment: The usual way to allow anyone to check whether the public key in question is indeed your public key is to publish a copy (or a fingerprint) of it on some web service. Furthermore, your public key is most likely wrapped in a X509 certificate, so that certificate should be the data you publish. Then anyone can compare the public key / certificate you published with the public key / certificate used during signature validation. Any solution requiring the use of the private key for a validation would make your private key susceptible to leakage.

Comment: I want to use the private key only for the validation at my service.
A verify to the users that the certificate is mine.

Comment: But why should the private key be used there if the easiest proof that the public key is yours is a comparison with a copy you provide. Furthermore, one can create multiple certificates for the same key pair. Thus, you'll have to check the certificate anyways for a positive answer that the certificate is indeed the right one...

Comment: Because I don't have approved ca authority certificate and someone can create a certificate with my details and sign with it.
I want to prevent it and approve the users that it's my signature.

Comment: @GalKoren But even if you don't have an approved CA authority, then you still don't need to use (and certainly not expose) your private key. A mechanism that involves using a private key for the validation of a signature is badly designed. Why don't you just share your public key online, so that people can verify if the public key in their PDF corresponds with your public key?

Comment: @GalKoren *"Because I don't have approved ca authority certificate and someone can create a certificate with my details and sign with it. I want to prevent it and approve the users that it's my signature."* - If you make your certificate publicly available, people can compare your copy with that fake copy, and that fake certificate will differ at least in the embedded public key. Thus, that comparison would uncover the fakes you are afraid of. Obviously you will have to think about ways to make MITM and similar attacks detectable but you'd also have to do that for any other web based solution.

Comment: Ok, so the solution is to 
1)extract the public key from the uploaded pdf.
2)compare it with my public key.

Additionally, publish the public key for users that know how to check it alone :)